# Cordova/UWP - how to deal with promises sequentially and write a routine to copy a folder recursively

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, uwp

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to utilise [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I'm trying to create a routine that will copy a folder and I find myself trying to deal with promises in sequence. The code that I've written isn't very elegant:

```
copyFolder = function( source, target ) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  var sourceFolder = null;
  var sourcePromise = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.getFolderAsync(sourcePath)

  sourcePromise.then(function(dir) {
    sourceFolder = dir;
  }, function(error) {
    return 
  });

  var targetFolder = null;
  var targetPromise = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.getFolderAsync(targetPath)

  targetPromise.then(function(dir) {
    targetFolder = dir;
  }

  $q.all( sourcePromise, targetPromise ).then( function() {
    if ( !targetFolder ) {
      var createPromise = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.createFolderAsync(targetPath)

      createPromise.then(function(dir) {
        targetFolder = dir;
      }
    }

    createPromise.then( function() {
      deferred.resolve( copyFolderRecursively(sourceFolder, targetFolder) );
    });
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Please note that I'm copying files that are in the Documents folder, so I can't use `cordova-plugin-file`.

In the case of the `targetFolder`, I'm checking to see if it exists (`targetPromise`). If it doesn't, I create it (`createPromise`). I like the idea of the `$q.all()` call, unfortunately it can't be used for `createPromise`.

To top it all off, I'm trying to create a recursive function that will return once all the files are copied. Actually, it would be better if it could return a promise (or build a list of promises).

Can this code be written in a more elegant form? Also, is there an example I can follow with a recursive function that implements a promise?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I can create a promise that depends on another promise and wait for that:

```
var targetFolder = null;
var targetPromise = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.getFolderAsync( target ).then( function() {
  return Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.getFolderAsync( target );
}, function(error) {
  return Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.createFolderAsync( target );
});

targetPromise.then( function(folder) {
  targetFolder = folder;
});
```

It's not ideal, but I treat the first call to `getFolderAsync` as an "exists" call. The success callback is then used to return the result of `getFolderAsync`. If the "exists" fails, then the call to `createFolderAsync` is made. This means that `$q.all( sourcePromise, targetPromise )` will wait until the folder is retrieved (or created). To keep things simple, instead of trapping the fail callback for `createFolderAsync` I just check to see whether `targetFolder` is defined.

Though this technically answers the first part of my question. I realised the following is much more concise:

```
var replace = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting;

var targetFolder = null;
var targetPromise = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary.createFolderAsync(target, replace);

targetPromise.then( function(folder) {
  targetFolder = folder;
});
```

What I'm not sure about is whether the `targetPromise.then` is executed sequentially before the `$q.all` (used at the end of the function). It seems to work, but I'm not sure whether it's supposed to.

I also created a function that will generate promises and wait for each copy operation (before resolving a single deferred promise). This is just the first version that worked. Any advice on how to improve it will be appreciated:

```
$scope.copyFolderRecursively = function(sourceFolder, targetFolder) {
  function CopySubFolders(sourcefolder, targetFolder) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if ( !sourceFolder ) return false;

    var promises = [];

    // Copy the files
    var getFilesPromise = sourceFolder.getFilesAsync();
    var copyFilesPromise = getFilesPromise.then(function (files) {
      if ( files ) {
        files.forEach(function (file) {
          console.log("copy file: " + file.displayName);

          var delayed = $q.defer();
          promises.push( delayed.promise );

          file.copyAsync(targetFolder).then( function(copiedfile) {
            delayed.resolve( copiedfile );
          }, function(error) {
            delayed.reject( "Error copying file" + file.path );
          });
        });
      }
    });

    // Recursively copy each subfolder
    var getFoldersPromise = sourceFolder.getFoldersAsync();
    var copyFoldersPromise = getFoldersPromise.then(function (folders) {
      if ( folders ) {
        folders.forEach(function (folder) {
          var replace = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting;
          console.log("create folder: " + folder.name);

          var delayed = $q.defer();
          promises.push( delayed.promise );

          targetFolder.createFolderAsync(folder.name, replace).then(function (newFolder) {
            CopySubFolders(folder, newFolder).then( function(success) {
              delayed.resolve( newFolder );
            }, function(error) {
              delayed.reject( "Error copying folder " + newFolder.path );
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });

    $q.all( getFilesPromise, copyFilesPromise, getFoldersPromise, copyFoldersPromise, promises ).then( function() {
      return $q.all( promises );
    }).then( function() {
      deferred.resolve( true );
    }, function(error) {
      deferred.resolve( false );
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return CopySubFolders( sourceFolder, targetFolder );
}
```

One thing worth noting with this solution (another realisation), [UWP promises](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx) are not [Angularjs promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). I basically convert each UWP call into an AngularJS deferred promise - so I can use `$q.all()`.